# Ignore missing variables in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I make Django (1.11) ignore missing variables in template during rendering? I need to render the same template with different data in multiple steps. I need to use the Django template engine for all the features that it includes and I can't modify the templates.

Instead of replacing them with an empty string:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context, TemplateSyntaxError

>>> c = Context({'foo': 'hello'})
>>> t = Template('{{foo}} {{bar}}')
>>> t.render(c)
'hello '
```

I would like it to just leave them as is

```
>>> t.render(c)
'hello {{bar}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `string_if_invalid` will work for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled

Your settings should add something like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            ...
            'string_if_invalid': '{{%s}}',
            ...
        },
    },
]
```

You may need to escape the curly braces, but I would be surprised if it didn't do that for you when replacing the string in.

Note that from the docs say:

> If string_if_invalid contains a '%s', the format marker will be replaced with the name of the invalid variable.

ALSO note that the docs say:

> For debug purposes only!
>
> While string_if_invalid can be a useful debugging tool, it is a bad idea to turn it on as a ‘development default’.
>
> Many templates, including those in the Admin site, rely upon the silence of the template system when a non-existent variable is encountered. If you assign a value other than '' to string_if_invalid, you will experience rendering problems with these templates and sites.
>
> Generally, string_if_invalid should only be enabled in order to debug a specific template problem, then cleared once debugging is complete.

EDIT: The doc's warning is making me a bit wary about using this. Give the above a try for debugging, but I wouldn't rely on it for a production system.

You might want to look into writing a custom template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag

It would be defined like this:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def preserve_invalid(context, var_name):
    return context.get(var_name, '{{%s}}' % var_name)
```

and used like this:

```
{% preserve_invalid "some_var" %}
```

Comment: I will only use the custom `string_if_invalid ` in a few places so that is a great solution for my problem :)